# WordPress options as array

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a customer who needs to have a database where he can create and edit his cars. I am not sure how I can add the cars to the options table so every the customer submits the form the data will be added to the existing row.

Let's say the option is called "scr_cars". When I call a get on that I would like to receive an array like so: `array('Toyota', 'Ford');`

I know it could be done through add_option() but I am not quite sure how to set up that validation, and I would like to know if this could be done through the register_setting().

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this section of the codex?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation

Comment: Yes, but I am still not sure.

Comment: There is this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress--wp-25536